# mysql/php: group by classes

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with percents (values 0-100) (let's assume table name=TableA with just 1 column named percent).

What I want to do is to divide the percents in classes. For example let's say that class width=2. My final result would be:

```
percent | quantity
------------------
[0-2)   | 5
[2-4)   | 43
...     | ...
[96-98) | 232
[98-100]| 173
```

I have thought some ways of doing this but i need an efficient one, taking into account that the table contains about 500.000 rows.
Finally i will create a chart in php, so i don't really care if the solution will be mysql-based or php-based.

1) (well that's for sure not the optimum but i'm writing it so that i make clear what i'm asking)

```
select count (*) from tableA where percent>=0 and percent<2;
select count (*) from tableA where percent>=2 and percent<4;
...
```

2) read each row using php and classify it

```
select * from tableA
<?php while ($row=...)
$class[intval($row[0]/50)]++; ?>
```

3) Create a table TableB like:

```
floor | roof
------------
0     | 2
2     | 4
4     | 6
...   | ...
```

and then

```
select tableB.floor/2,count(*) 
from tableA join tableB 
on tableA.percent>=tableB.floor and tableA.percent<tableB.roof
group by tableB.floor/2
```

I like more the second one, although I'm not sure if it's better to make the calculations by using php or by using mysql.

Do you have any better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your histogram buckets with a formula, without the help of your second table.

```
SELECT count(*), FLOOR(percent/2)*2 percent
  FROM tableA
 GROUP BY FLOOR(percent/2)*2
 ORDER BY FLOOR(percent/2)*2
```

This should be very efficient, especially if you happen to have an index on your `percent` column.

For example, `percent` values of 18 and 19 will be converted to 18 by the GROUP BY formula.

Comment: Good answer, +1. Only the `*2` in the GROUP BY and ORDER BY clauses seems superfluous – whether you group and sort by 0, 2, 4, … or 0, 1, 2, … should make no difference at all. (On the other hand, such a simple mathematical operation most likely costs almost nothing, so for consistency and better understandability of the query at first glance one just might want to leave it in.)

Comment: Correct: The  *2 multiplication is for display purposes in the result set. I have the habit, learned from too many years of Oracle hacking, of always using the same expression in the SELECT and the GROUP BY.